# PowerShell Regex for nested XML tags

Tags: regex, xml, powershell

I need to repair several huge buggy XML files.
Because they are buggy, I cannot just do:

```
[xml]$xml = Get-Content .\data.xml
```

I want to parse them with captured groups.
However, I don't know how to handle nested tags.

Here is a simple example to illustrate my problem.

```
$xml = '<tag><tag><tag>Anything</tag><tag>Something else</tag></tag><tag><tag>Another value</tag><tag>And another one...</tag></tag></tag>'
$Pattern = '<tag>(?<Content>.+?)</tag>'
([regex]::Matches($Xml, $Pattern)).Value
```

This piece of code returns:

```
<tag><tag><tag>Anything</tag>
<tag>Something else</tag>
<tag><tag>Another value</tag>
<tag>And another one...</tag>
```

How can I change my Regex pattern to get this?

```
<tag>Anything</tag>
<tag>Something else</tag>
<tag>Another value</tag>
<tag>And another one...</tag>
```

It seems that Regex recursion would fit my needs.
However, I couldn't find someone explaining how it works with PowerShell (if ever...)

Comment: .NET regex does not support recursion. It supports balanced constructs. And Powershell has an XML parser.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks for this information. I will try to find some documentation about this technique.

Comment: Why use lookahead? Use `<tag>(?<Content>[^<]*)</tag>`

Comment: And why not? :-) There seems to be several possible way to get the same result. Just searched for the meaning. Really interesting too. Thanks for this interesting suggestion.

Comment: Marco's solution will [also match](https://regex101.com/r/d0flMC/1) `<tag><font><tag>Anything</font></tag>` in `<tag><tag><font><tag>Anything</font></tag></tag>`. Not sure what you need.

Comment: Yes I have to look at the global result of my script. Thanks for the warning!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Negative lookahead is enough.

```
<tag>(?!<tag>)(?<Content>.+?)<\/tag>
```

It takes only the last `<tag>`, which is the one that passes the lookahead check.

Answer (score 0):

Your "specification" consists of a single example of input and desired output, which isn't necessarily a very good basis for writing code, but for the given example you could adopt the approach of replacing any sequence of `<tag>` start tags with a single `<tag>` start tag, and any sequence of `</tag>` end tags with a single `</tag>` end tag.

So replace `(<tag>)+` by `<tag>`, and `(</tag>)+` by `</tag>`.

If I have misunderstood the question, then you need to find a way to describe the problem more clearly.

Of course, repairing bad XML is no substitute for fixing the buggy code that generated the bad XML in the first place.

Comment: I didn't think about this technique, but it would do the job too. Thanks!